# Nested objects for geoJSON using Element API

Tags: plugin-elementapi

I'm trying to create a GeoJSON feed using the Element API plugin but having difficulty creating the nested structure required for the JSON object:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "Dinagat Islands"
  }
}
```

I can get a flat json structure using:

```
...

return [
    "type" => "Feature",
    "geometry" => "",
    "properties" => ""
];

...
```

My question is, how would I update the above code to create the nested json objects for `geometry` and `properties`?

Thanks. G.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out myself. I needed to use PHP array syntax.

In answer to my own question, the updated code for a nested object would be:

```
...

return [
    "type" => "Feature",
    "geometry" => array("type" => "Point", "coordinates" => [125.6, 10.1]),
    "properties" => array("name" => "Dinagat Islands")
];

...
```

Hope this helps someone else as it wasn't immediately apparent to me.